# Публикация результата через Facebook SDK для Unity: как получить разрешение на publish_actions?

Tags: c#, unity3d, facebook

До публикации приложения нужно протестировать отправку результатов игр в Facebook.

Для этого надо получить разрешение на `publish_actions`, что у меня сделать не вышло.

Создал в Facebook свое приложение, вызываю такой код:

```
List<string> publishPermissions = new List<string>{ "publish_actions" };
FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(publishPermissions, callback);
```

Мне в редакторе Unity показывают модальное окно Facebook, в нем щелкаю на *Find Access Token*:

[image: Изображение модального окна]

Перехожу в Facebook, там копирую *User Token*:

[image: Изображение User Token на странице Facebook]

Вношу его в прежде упомянутое окно `Unity` и нажимаю `Send Success`:

[image: Изображение с окном ввода User Token]

В результате среди разрешенных permission нет `publish_actions` и среди отклоненных тоже:

[image: Результат]

Что я не так настроил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел - чтобы получить право publish_actions без прохождения ревью приложения надо:

1. Пройти по https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
2. Выбрать свое приложение из выпадающего списка справа сверху
3. Нажать Get Access Token
4. Выбрать разрешения, которые нужны
5. Использовать этот токен
6. Если надо можно увеличить срок действия токена до нескольких месяцев, вместо нескольких часов - идем по адресу https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/
7. Нажимаем на Debug напротив User Token, а далее - кнопку Extend Access Token

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы получить право `publish_actions`, нужно проходить ревью приложения на [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-publish_actions)